# How do I change an email address with an @ in a colored textField?

Tags: user-interface, swiftui, interface

I'm currently creating a registration system but my email address is in blue with the arobase in swiftUI. How can I change the color to gray?

```swift
TextField("exampl@email.com", text: $Useremail, onEditingChanged: { editing in
                        if !editing {
                            Error = !isEmailValid
                            
                        }
                    })
                    .font(Font.system(size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
```

I tried a TextEditor

Comment: You can use `.tint(.gray)`

Comment: 'tint' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer

Add @available attribute to enclosing property

Comment: You could change the accentColor in the assets.

Comment: I have nothing in accentColor

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    TextField("example@mail.com", text: $userMail)
        .tint(.gray)
} else {
    TextField("example@mail.com", text: $userMail)
        .accentColor(.gray)
}
```

Comment: you've completely changed my code

Comment: I have simplified it so it can be helpful for everyone. Feel free to take/modify just what you need for your specific case. Also, pay attention to not downvote everyone's answer, we're taking our time to help you for free, don't abuse it...

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to use `.accentColor(.gray)`